# IVP in which Picard iterates don't converge

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, initial-value-problems

I need to exhibit an example of a IVP problem in which the Picard iterates do not converge. I was thinking about something involving a function who is not integrable, or trying to set $y(0)=y_0=0$ in the initial value problem of the type
$$\begin{cases}
f(t.y)=y'\\
y(t_0)=y_0
\end{cases}$$
and somehow define $f$ so that the quantity
$$g_1(t)=\int_0^t f(s,0)ds = \infty$$
where $g_1(t)$ is the first Picard iterate. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Moo I'm not looking for an example where Picard's theorem does not hold because the function doesn't satisfy the hypothesis, but rather a IVP in which the sequence of Picard iterates do not converge (in the example you quote, the sequence of iterates converges to the $0$ function which is a solution)

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the first iteration starting from $y(0) = 0$ to blow up?

Comment: @copper.hat The $t_0$ and $y_0$ don't need to to be $0$, that was just whatI started doing. I was thinking that maybe using $f(t)=1/t$ would work, but I'm not sure. And if the first iteration blows up, then the sequence wouldn't converge, or would it?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Do you want $g_1(t) = \infty$ for al $t >0$?

Comment: @copper.hat what I am looking for is that picard iterations do not converge, it does not necessarily have to be in the first, but the idea is to find some function whose iterates do not converge
(if the function is not lipschitz, the better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $y'=y^2$ with $y(0) = 1$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

A small bit of work shows that if $y_0(x) =1$, and $y_{n+1}(x) = 1+ \int_0^x y_n(t)^2 dt $, then
$y_n(x) \ge 1+ x + \cdots + x^n$, for $x \in [0,1]$.

In fact, if we let $y(x)= {1 \over 1-x}$ for $x \in [0,1)$, it is straightforward to show that if $y_n(x) \le y(x)$ for $x \in [0,1)$ then $y_{n+1}(x)\le y(x)$ for $x \in [0,1)$.

We see that for $x \in [0,1)$ we have $y_n(x) \to y(x)$, and
$y_n(1) \to \infty$.